# Parameter initialization error with PlanSys2 and BT's

Tags: ros2, parameters

I'm trying to implement PlanSys2 and Behavior trees. My package is heavily inspired by [ros2_planning_system_examples plansys2_bt_example package](https://github.com/PlanSys2/ros2_planning_system_examples). I want to simulate a warehouse robot with automatic planning. The package is launched by launching *plansys2_bringup* from [ros2_planning_system](https://github.com/PlanSys2/ros2_planning_system/tree/humble-devel) and some behavior tree nodes.

Launch file snippet

```
plansys2_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('plansys2_bringup'),
        'launch',
        'plansys2_bringup_launch_monolithic.py')),
    launch_arguments={
        'model_file': os.path.join(this_directory, 'pddl', 'domain.pddl'),
        'namespace': namespace
    }.items()
)

# set actions
# pass params and BT node to the action node
navigate_cmd = Node(
    package='plansys2_bt_actions',
    executable='bt_action_node',
    name='navigate',
    namespace=namespace,
    output='screen',
    parameters=[
        os.path.join(this_directory, 'config', 'params.yaml'),
        {
            'action_name': 'navigate',
            'publisher_port': 1668,
            'server_port': 1669,
            'bt_xml_file': os.path.join(this_directory, 'bt_xml', 'navigate.xml')
        }
    ]
)
```

The params for *navigate* (behavior tree node) from *params.yaml* is

```
navigate:
  ros__parameters:
    plugins:
    - plansys2_navigate_bt_node
    waypoints: ["charging_station", "unload_zone", "reol_1", "reol_2", "reol_3", "reol_4"]
    waypoint_coordinates:
      charging_station: [-2.0, -0.5, 0.0]
      unload_zone: [2.0, 0.5, 0.0]
      reol_1: [0.5, 2.0, 0.0]
      reol_2: [-0.5, 2.0, 0.0]
      reol_3: [0.5, -2.0, 0.0]
      reol_4: [-0.5, -2.0, 0.0]
```

where I set the params *waypoints* and *waypoints_coordinates*.
The first part of BT node *navigate*'s constructor is

```
Navigate::Navigate(const std::string &xml_tag, const std::string &action_name,
               const BT::NodeConfiguration &configuration):
               plansys2::BtActionNode<nav2_msgs::action::NavigateToPose>(xml_tag,
                                                                         action_name,                                                                   
                                                                       configuration)
{
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr ros_node;
  BT::TreeNode::config().blackboard->get("node", ros_node);

  try{
    std::cout << "Trying to declare parameter 'waypoints'..." << std::endl;
    ros_node->declare_parameter<std::vector<std::string>>("waypoints");
    std::cout << "Declared parameter 'waypoints'." << std::endl;
    
  } catch (const rclcpp::exceptions::ParameterAlreadyDeclaredException &e){
      // pass
  }

  ...
```

where I've added print statements for debugging. The package is running until

`ros_node->declare_parameter<std::vector<std::string>>("waypoints");`

where the package returns

```
[bt_action_node-2] Trying to declare parameter 'waypoints'...
[bt_action_node-2] [ERROR] [1708975502.584947181] [navigate]: Caught exception in 
callback for transition 13
[bt_action_node-2] [ERROR] [1708975502.584966297] [navigate]: Original error: 
Statically typed parameter 'waypoints' must be initialized.
[bt_action_node-2] [WARN] [1708975502.584980393] [navigate]: Error occurred while 
doing error handling.
```

when running a ROS 2 node *task_controller_node* that set instances and predicates for a PDDL solver.

I thought this had to do with *waypoints* parameter not being correclty declared/initialized/set. Running *ros2 param list /navigate* do indeed show that there is no parameters *waypoints* or *waypoint_coordiantes*. However, all other parameters, like *action_name* and *plugins* is available. I tried to set the parameters direclty in the *navigate* BT node but I get the same error. I have no clue why some parameters are loaded and others are not. Is there anything I missed when declaring/initializing parameters or could it be a problem elsewhere in the code?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks:)